# What is the legal status of entering a ticketed music event without a ticket?

Tags: criminal-law, england-and-wales

Bob Dylan is playing in Alice's city next week, but she doesn't have a ticket. she somehow manages to sneak into the venue without being noticed but is then later caught. Has  Alice committed a criminal offence?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140015/discussion-on-question-by-josephcorrectenglishpronouns-what-is-the-legal-status).

Answer (score 6):

### [Obtaining services dishonestly](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2006/35/section/11)

It is an either-way offence punishable by 12 months summarily or 5 years on indictment and/or a fine in both cases.

Comment: How can anything be punishable by more than 6 months summarily?

Comment: Anyway, what distinguishes this from a simple civil trespass where a Bob Dylan simply happened to be going on?

Comment: https://law.stackexchange.com/q/64799/32669

Comment: @JosephCorrectEnglishPronouns Bob’s intention distinguishes it

Answer (score 1):

### [germany](/questions/tagged/germany): Erschleichung von Leistungen

[StGB § 265a](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stgb/__265a.html) (1) makes it a crime that is punished by 1 year to try to bypass a payment to acquire transport service, gain access to a venue or to get a machine's products without actually paying and having the intent not to pay. (2)The attempt is punishable.

The market rate for a Bob Dylan concert ticket at the London Palladium for 20th of October 2022 costs at between 220€ and 260€ from the ticket distributors at the same day. As a result, this is not a *low value* thing, it is an outright crime for which [StGB §248a](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stgb/__248a.html) can't be applied as 265a offers - the ticket isn't [*geringwertig*,](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geringwertige_Sache). Usually, courts have decide the edge of when an item is of low value and would need special interest or request of the damaged to have crimes prosecuted. The common line is usually 50€. One such example would be [2 Ss 427/03 OLG Hamm](https://dejure.org/dienste/vernetzung/rechtsprechung?Gericht=OLG%20Hamm&Datum=28.07.2003&Aktenzeichen=2%20Ss%20427/03) (dejure), also called ["43 bars of chocolate"](https://www.burhoff.de/rspr/texte/aw_00003.htm) (full text, german):

> Der Senat ist mit der Revision der Auffassung, dass diese Rechtsprechung unter Berücksichtigung der seitdem eingetretenen Kosten- und Preissteigerung als überholt anzusehen und die Grenze heute bei 50 EURO zu ziehen ist (so auch, allerdings ohne nähere Begründung, OLG Zweibrücken NStZ 2000, 536 = StV 2000, 298).

> With the revision, the Senate [=revision entity] is of the opinion that this case law [originally marking 25€ as the line] is to be regarded as outdated, taking into account the cost and price increases that have occurred since then [in the 1980s], and that the limit today should be set at 50 euros (as decided likewise, but without further justification, OLG Zweibrücken NStZ 2000, 536 = StV 2000, 298).